# How guard nil in math function if it drops with bad argument in arithmetic expression

Tags: graphql, elixir, ecto

Trying figure out, while generating GQL schema,
why if `:float` data in source var `square_plot` exists (say `50`),
there is no ERR
but if it is NIL the code generates error
while i converting value so *sqft* with such code:

may be it seems no validation passes

CODE

```
field(:square_plot, :float)     // my var is `50.0` in DB

field :square_plot_ft, :float do
  if square_plot > 0 do
    resolve(fn _args, %{source: source} -> {:ok, Float.round(source.square_plot*10.7639, 0)} end)
  end
end
```

if value NOT NIL the GQL response

```
{
    "data": {
        "unit": {
            "squareTotalFt": 1615.0,
            "squareTotal": 150.0,
            "squarePlotFt": 538.0,
            "squarePlot": 50.0
        }
    }
}
```

if value is NIL the GQL response

```
"Internal server error"
```

and server  ERR

```
** (exit) an exception was raised:
    ** (ArithmeticError) bad argument in arithmetic expression
        (platform) lib/units_web/schema/object.ex:228: anonymous fn/2 in UnitsWeb.Schema.Unit.__abs
inthe_type__/1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surprisingly enough, in [erlang](/questions/tagged/erlang), and therefore in [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir), comparisons `<`/`>` involving different types are legal.

Even more surprisingly, any atom is greater than any number (see [Atom Ordering](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#module-term-ordering) in the documentation.)

```elixir
nil > 0
#⇒ true
```

and we get into `if`, attempting `square_plot*10.7639` which is `nil*10.7639`, which obviously raises.

The proper code would be:

```elixir
field :square_plot_ft, :float do
  if is_number(square_plot) and square_plot > 0 do
    resolve(...)
  end
end
```